# Help with Duplicate Lead Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

My Duplicate lead trigger works fine except I cannot figure out how to set a date parameter into the equation as well. I would like it so that a a lead with a duplicate email address as another in our system will only pass IF it was created at least a week after the original was created. Could someone give me a hand please? Here is my Trigger

```
trigger DetectDupes on Lead (before insert, before update)
{
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
    //Make sure the lead has an email address
    {
        if (l.Email != null)
        {
            //Find a duplicate
            String leadEmail = l.Email;
            String leadId = l.Id; 
            Date leadCreateDate = l.CreatedDate.date();
            Date todayDate = Date.today();

            List<Lead> dupeLeads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Email = :leadEmail AND Id != :leadId AND todayDate >= :l.CreatedDate + 7 ];

            //If a duplicate is found, update the Dupe_Lead__c field. There is a validation rule that will not allow the record to save if this field is populated.
            if (dupeLeads.size() > 0)
            {
                l.Dupe_Lead__c = dupeLeads[0].Id;
            }
            else
            {
                l.Dupe_Lead__c = null;
            }
        }    
        else 
        {
             l.Dupe_Lead__c = null;   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: date d = system.today().addDays(-7);
lead [] acc=  [select id from Lead where createdDate = :d];

Comment: You need to put the lead query outside of the FOR loop.  Otherwise, if more than 100 leads go through this trigger, it will blow up.  100 Leads - assuming you don't have any other triggers on Leads.  If you do, then probably even fewer than 100 will cause a SOQL limit exception.

Comment: I have never done that before, how would you suggest I write that and will it involve maps?